# sed to find and replace a string with special characters

Tags: linux, sed

Trying to replace

```
window.location = '/loft-run'+ResourceManager.hotlegs + mainPage + ".html#" + newhash;
```

to

```
window.location = ResourceManager.hotlegs + mainPage + ".html#" + newhash;
```

in a file. what I have tried

```
sed -i 's~/loft-run'+ResourceManager.hotlegs + mainPage + ".html#" + newhash"~ResourceManager.hotlegs + mainPage + ".html#" + newhash"' warmblanket.js
```

Have tried some sed commands but not much of help.
Your suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: The code you posted cannot be executed. Both the first and the second version. The reason is easy: There are three unmasked `'` in the `sed` command line (most of which is not quoted at all so the whole line is really broken).

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
sed -i "s@'/loft-run'\+@@" warmblanket.js
```

- the basic form for substitution is `s/before/after/`
- use *double quotes* if you want to treat *single quotes*
- chosen the `@` delimiter here instead of basic `/`, you can pick up most of the ASCII table

Answer (score 0):

sed doesn't know about literal strings, just regexps and backreference-enabled text. To do anything with literal strings just use a tool that understands them such as awk:

```
$ cat file
window.location = '/loft-run'+ResourceManager.hotlegs + mainPage + ".html#" + newhash;

$ awk \
    -v old="window.location = '/loft-run'+ResourceManager.hotlegs + mainPage + \".html#\" + newhash;" \
    -v new='window.location = ResourceManager.hotlegs + mainPage + ".html#" + newhash;' \
    's=index($0,old) { $0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old)) } 1' file
window.location = ResourceManager.hotlegs + mainPage + ".html#" + newhash;
```

Note the use of `"` instead of `'` around the `old=...` string because that string includes `'`s and shell doesn't allow `'`s inside a `'`-delimited string.